# Why disposing StreamReader makes a stream unreadable?

Tags: c#, stream, idisposable, streamreader

I need to read a stream two times, from start to end.

But the following code throws an `ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed file` exception.

```
string fileToReadPath = @"<path here>";
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileToReadPath, FileMode.Open))
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs))
    {
        string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }

    fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); // ObjectDisposedException thrown.

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs))
    {
        string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
```

Why is it happening? What is really disposed? And why manipulating `StreamReader` affects the associated stream in this way? Isn't it logical to expect that a seekable stream can be read several times, including by several `StreamReader`s?

Comment: Also consider using System.IO.File.ReadAllText() in situations like these.  It's simpler.

Comment: @Dave Markle: you're right. I've put it like a short example. Actually, in the real code, streams I deal with can be very big, so the first reader reads them line per line, then, the stream is copied per-byte to another stream.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This happens because the `StreamReader` takes over 'ownership' of the stream.  In other words, it makes itself responsible for closing the source stream.  As soon as your program calls `Dispose` or `Close` (leaving the `using` statement scope in your case) then it will dispose the source stream as well.  Calling `fs.Dispose()` in your case.  So the file stream is dead after leaving the first `using` block.  It is consistent behavior, all stream classes in .NET that wrap another stream behave this way.

There is one constructor for `StreamReader` that allows saying that it *doesn't* own the source stream.  It is however not accessible from a .NET program, the constructor is internal.

In this particular case, you'd solve the problem by not using the `using`-statement for the `StreamReader`.  That's however a fairly hairy implementation detail.  There's surely a better solution available to you but the code is too synthetic to propose a real one.

Answer (score 7):

The purpose of `Dispose()` is to clean up resources when you're finished with the stream.  The reason the *reader* impacts the *stream* is because the reader is just filtering the stream, and so disposing the reader has no meaning except in the context of it chaining the call to the source stream as well.

To fix your code, just use one reader the entire time:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileToReadPath, FileMode.Open))
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs))
{
    string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(text);

    fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); // ObjectDisposedException not thrown now

    text = reader.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(text);
}
```

**Edited to address comments below**:

In most situations, you do not need to access the underlying stream as you do in your code (`fs.Seek`).  In these cases, the fact that `StreamReader` chains its call to the underlying stream allows you to economize on the code by not using a `usings` statement for the stream at all.  For example, the code would look like:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(new FileStream(fileToReadPath, FileMode.Open)))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: In fact, I'm asking why Dispose() on the *reader* affects the *stream*. I don't understand your answer. Does it mean that readers Dispose has only a purpose to clean the stream data? So why even `StreamReader` implements `IDisposable`, if it doesn't do anything *useful* (since disposing the stream itself will in all cases do all the work)?

Comment: @MainMa, the purpose of Dispose() is *always* to make sure all resources associated with the given `IDisposable` are cleaned up.  Since the reader and the stream represent the same entity disposing of one has the same effect as disposing the other.

Answer (score 2):

`Using` defines a scope, outside of which an object will be disposed, thus the `ObjectDisposedException`. You can't access the StreamReader's contents outside of this block.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your question. The biggest issue with this intentional side-effect is when developers don't know about it and are blindly following the "best practice" of surrounding a StreamReader with a `using`. But it can cause some really hard to track down bugs when it is on a long-lived object's property, the best (worst?) example I've seen is

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream))
{
    body = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

The developer had no idea the InputStream is now hosed for any future place that expects it to be there.

Obviously, once you know the internals you know to avoid the `using` and just read and reset the position. But I thought a core principle of API design was to avoid side effects, especially not destroying data you are acting upon. Nothing inherent about a class that supposedly is a "reader" should clear the data it reads when done "using" it. Disposing of the reader should release any references to the Stream, not clear the stream itself. The only thing I can think is that the choice had to be made since the reader is altering other internal state of the Stream, like the position of the seek pointer, that they assumed if you are wrapping a using around it you are intentionally going to be done with everything. On the other hand, just like in your example, if you are creating a Stream, the stream itself will be in a `using`, but if you are reading a Stream that was created outside of your immediate method, it is presumptuous of the code to clear the data.

What I do and tell our developers to do on Stream instances that the reading code doesn't explicitly create is...

```
// save position before reading
long position = theStream.Position;
theStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
// DO NOT put this StreamReader in a using, StreamReader.Dispose() clears the stream
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(theStream);
string content = sr.ReadToEnd();
theStream.Seek(position, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

(sorry I added this as an answer, wouldn't fit in a comment, I would love more discussion about this design decision of the framework)

Comment: A better design for a StreamReader would have been to have a constructor argument specify whether it should take ownership of the stream.  There are many situations where code may open a stream, create a reader for it, hand the reader off to something that will read the data at a future time, and then have no further use for the stream.  In that situation, the stream should be disposed when the reader is done with it, but the creator of the stream may have no idea when that will be.

Answer (score 0):

`Dispose()` on parent will `Dispose()` all owned streams.  Unfortunately, streams don't have `Detach()` method, so you have to create some workaround here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but you can leave your StreamReader undisposed. That way your underlying stream won't be disposed, even when StreamReader got collected.

Comment: Of course. But it's not too intuitive to not put a using to a `StreamReader` for me, and it will probably violate FxCop rules. By the way, the issue at the origin of this question appeared when I refactored and old code where usings were completely missing.